# Is there any method like count to produce the output below

Tags: count, tuples

```py
def test_normal(self):
    word = "abcdef"
    output = [
        ("a", 1),
        ("b", 1),
        ("c", 1),
        ("d", 1),
        ("e", 1),
        ("f", 1)
    ]

print(letter_count(word = "abcdef")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter


def letter_count(word):
    return list(Counter(word).items())


print(letter_count(word="abcdef"))
```

Prints:

```py
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('d', 1), ('e', 1), ('f', 1)]
```

Comment: thanks u so much what would i do in the word counter